# MDX Last Child with Filter

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am using the following calculation in my cube to get balances for P&L and Balance Sheet accounts. this is working fine but the problem is that this code doesn't work if I have filters on the date dimension.

For example, let's say I am looking at amounts for the 4 quarters for 2014 - the sub-total in this case for balance sheet accounts would be the Amount in 2014 Q4(and the calculation works correctly). However, if when am looking at say two quarters Q1 and Q2 for 2014, the calculation still shows the sub-total as the Amount in 2014 Q4 whereas the correct value should be Amount in 2014 Q2. I have pasted a screen shot of Excel pivot table also.

```
CASE [Accounts].[Account Type].CurrentMember.MemberValue 
    WHEN 'Balance Sheet' 
        THEN ([Dates].[Hierarchy].currentMember.lastChild, [Measures].[Measures].[Amount]) 
    ELSE Amount 
END
```

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You should use `[Accounts].[Account Type].CurrentMember IS [Accounts].[Account Type].[Balance Sheet]` to check for member identity.

Comment: Where do you apply the filters? In the column? Which version of Excel and Analysis Services are you using, and are you using an XLS or an XLSX file? I think to remember that there is some different behavior of Excel depending on these versions.

Comment: @FrankPl- thanks, I am using XLSX. I am applying the filter on columns to the dates hierarchy as shown in the screen shot above.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this is achievable as there seems to be an inconsistency between the client filter and the calculation on the cube. Maybe if the calculation was in the pivot it would work. I'll have a play.

Comment: @sam what you're trying to do does not seem possible. Do you know Excel's cube functions - it will be possible to create something, not as dynamic as a pivot data but still semi-dynamic using these functions.